# Calling multiple keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I want to call the keys of this value.

```
normalswords={"TRAINING SWORD":["A sword meant for training", "no element", 10, "damage"]}
```

Instead of just calling one by typing:

```
print (normalswords["TRAINING SWORD"][1])
```

I want it to print out certain keys

```
print (normalswords["TRAINING SWORD"][0][2])
```

This is not the same as printing the entire thing

Answer (score 1):

`print (normalswords["TRAINING SWORD"][0][2])` would print element #2 OF element #0 (in other words, the 's' in 'A sword'), NOT elements #0 and #2.

The closest built-in feature to what you're talking about would probably be:

```
print("{0} {2}".format(*normalswords["TRAINING SWORD"]))
```

or

```
print("{0[0]} {0[2]}".format(normalswords["TRAINING SWORD"]))
```

using string formatting to pick out the desired list items. The asterisk in the first version splits up the list into the equivalent of four separate parameters; the second version avoids that, but must use a fancier field specifications to pick out the elements of the single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `operator` module has `itemgetter()` which you can provide multiple indexes, e.g.:

```
import operator as op
details = op.itemgetter(0, 2)
print(details(normalswords["TRAINING SWORD"]))
```